# Hackerrank: Breaking the records

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, recursion, unit-testing, clojure

I'm learning Clojure and am a rank n00b at it, trying to learn from books and online tutorials (but I'm sometimes concerned that I am picking up bad habits or at least not all the good habits). For exercise I did the [Breaking the Records](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/breaking-best-and-worst-records) problem on Hackerrank.

### TL;DR problem description:

**For a list of scores (in historic order), count the number of times the previous best score was exceeded as well as the previous worst score was undercut.**

In an iterative language it is quite easy to [just iterate through the list](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/188606); but Clojure does not do iteration and I decided to tackle this problem for exercise in constructing a (tail end) recursive solution. To make it easier for myself, I first did a recursive solution in Java, which I then translated. All in all, it's quite a simple recursive function without rocket surgery involved.

Obviously my code works, as shown by the included unit tests. My concerns are however as follows:

- When put next to the Java code, the two look fairly similar. Did I follow "idiomatic" Clojure programming, or is it just a clumsy "word-for-word transliteration"?
- Are there any areas that could have been more compact and/or easier to understand by using different Clojure constructs?

Your critical input will be highly appreciated - **including regarding the unit testing**, as that is arguably an important part of programming, which I want to learn and practice in parallel.

Code:

```clojure
(ns hackerrank.breaking-records
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(defrecord Record [min max countworse countbetter])

(defn recalc-record [rec newscore]
  (Record.
    (min newscore (:min rec))
    (max newscore (:max rec))
    (+ (:countworse rec) (if (> (:min rec) newscore) 1  0))
    (+ (:countbetter rec) (if (< (:max rec) newscore) 1  0))))

(defn accumulate [curr-record remaining-scores]
  (if (nil? (second remaining-scores))
    curr-record
    (recur (recalc-record curr-record (second remaining-scores)) (rest remaining-scores)))
)

(defn breaking-records [scores]
  (let [result (accumulate (Record. (first scores) (first scores) 0 0) scores)]
    (list (:countbetter result) (:countworse result))))

(deftest test-records
  (testing "edge cases"
    (is (= '(0 0) (breaking-records '())) "no games played yet")
    (is (= '(0 0) (breaking-records '(5))) "single game"))
  (testing "hackerrank examples"
    (is (= '(2 4) (breaking-records '(10 5 20 20 4 5 2 25 1))))
    (is (= '(4 0) (breaking-records '(3 4 21 36 10 28 35 5 24 42)))))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote your solution to use more typical Clojure features.  When you are looping over data and need to keep track of accumulated state, it is hard to beat `loop/recur`.  A first example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use clojure.test))

(defn breaking-records
  [scores]
  ; this loop has 5 variables. Init all of them
  (loop [low         (first scores)
         high        (first scores)
         nworse      0
         nbetter     0
         score-pairs (partition 2 1 scores)]
    (if (empty? score-pairs)
      {:nbetter nbetter :nworse nworse}
      (let [curr-score-pair (first score-pairs)
            new-score       (second curr-score-pair)]
        ; start the next iteration with modified versions of the 5 loop vars
        (recur
          (min new-score low)
          (max new-score high)
          (if (< new-score low)
            (inc nworse)
            nworse)
          (if (< high new-score)
            (inc nbetter)
            nbetter)
          (rest score-pairs))))))
```

and unit tests:

```
(deftest test-records
  (testing "edge cases"
    (is (= (breaking-records []) {:nbetter 0 :nworse 0}) "no games played yet")
    (is (= (breaking-records [5]) {:nbetter 0 :nworse 0}) "single game"))
  (testing "hackerrank examples"
    (is (= (breaking-records [10 5 20 20 4 5 2 25 1]) {:nbetter 2 :nworse 4}))
    (is (= (breaking-records [3 4 21 36 10 28 35 5 24 42]) {:nbetter 4 :nworse 0}))))

; ***** NOTE: it's much easier to use vectors like [1 2 3] instead of a quoted list `(1 2 3)
```

Please see [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), esp. the Clojure CheatSheet. Also, the template project as a whole shows how I like to structure things.  :)

The function that helps the most is `partition`.  [See the docs](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition).

---

### Slight refactoring

You can simplify it a small amount and make it a bit more compact by using more specialized functions like `reduce` and `cond->`.  This version uses a map to hold state and `reduce` to perform the looping:

```
(defn breaking-records
  [scores]
  (let [state-init     {:low     (first scores)
                        :high    (first scores)
                        :nworse  0
                        :nbetter 0}
        accum-stats-fn (fn [state score-pair]
                         ; Use map destructuring to pull out the 4 state variables
                         (let [{:keys [low high nworse nbetter]} state 
                               new-score (second score-pair)
                               state-new {:low     (min new-score low)
                                          :high    (max new-score high)
                                          :nworse  (cond-> nworse
                                                     (< new-score low) (inc))
                                          :nbetter (cond-> nbetter
                                                     (< high new-score) (inc))}]
                           state-new))
        state-final    (reduce accum-stats-fn
                         state-init
                         (partition 2 1 scores))
        result         (select-keys state-final [:nworse :nbetter])]
    result))
```

Comment: I *highly* appreciate you taking the time to do this, it does point me to some areas I should be focusing on for learning. It does seem you have not bought into the "small functions" exhortations of the Clean Code book/ideology :-) (To be honest, I have started to get second thoughts about that bit too. Ironically, Robert C. Martin's enthusiasm regarding Clojure was a contributing factor for my interest in it.) Also, is there a specific reason for [] being "much easier" than '(), *apart* from the one extra character and it standing out from the surrounding parentheses?

Comment: When you print a quoted list, the quote disappears, so you always have to add it back when you cut/paste.  Same for double-quotes on a string, which is why keywords are nicer for non-user data (e.g. `:nworse`).